# Make back end APIs only accessible via Azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have multiple Web APIs deployed in Azure without applying authentication, so anyone has access to internet has the access to the Web APIs.

Now I would like to apply authentications to the Web APIs, instead of implementing the same authentication logic in different Web APIs, I found Azure API gateway (API management) is a potential solution.

With Azure API management documentation, I learned I can apply policies like `validate-jwt` to authenticate requests to back end Web APIs. However, endpoints of the back end Web APIs are still available to users.

So, how should I hide them? Must I define a sub network or does Azure API management have a feature for this?

Answer (score 11):

Recently I also had this same problem. Finally I found the solution by using 'IP Restrictions' function. See the following steps:

1) Go to your API management Overview page in Azure portal, copy the VIP.
[image: API management Overview page]

2) In your Web APP > Networking
[image: networking]

3) Paste in your VIP
[image: paste vip]

Comment: Unfortunately IP's change; e.g. here is announcement from Microsoft about changes in IP's for API Management: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/05/31/potential-change-to-api-management-ip-addresses/

Comment: Very interesting (+1), I wasn't aware of that @Neil, it's pretty rare though I would of thought? Are you aware of it changing often?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith it should be very rare; but did happen once already; so probably would be useful to set some monitoring/alarms just in case.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith I've also asked a related question from MS; and here is there reply (I've posted as one of the answers here as well): https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26312#issuecomment-470105156

Comment: This works but not an ideal solution. Better try this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity

Comment: According to the feature list (May 2022), all instances except on consumption plan should now have static IP's - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's Solution: [How to secure back-end services using client certificate authentication in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates)

Using this approach, any attempt to access a back-end service without the required certificate will result in a `403 - Forbidden` response.

You can use a self-signed certificate as opposed to using a trusted CA signed certificate ($$).  I chose to implement an Azure Key Vault where I generated a new certificate, downloaded it as a *.PFX file, and uploaded it into my API Management instance as described in the article.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you don't want to spend money on a private azure network

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer from @PramodValavala-MSFT
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26312#issuecomment-470105156

Here are options:

- [IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) (as described by @redman)
- [Function keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys)
- [Authentication/Authorization for Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)
- [Managed Identity for APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity)

p.s. in my case I want with IP restrictions since it allows to keep all of the auth on the API Management Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use:

1. Basic auth
2. Mutual certificate auth
3. VPN

to secure Azure API Management service communication with your backend service.

Answer (score 1):

Look into setting up TLS on Azure API Management so that all connections to your backend API must come through the API proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Azure API management cannot modify your backend service. It's role is limited to being a proxy.

You will have to apply authentications to each Web API or configure your firewall to accept requests only from Azure APIM.

Answer (score 0):

Is your backend app an Azure Function app or an App Service app?

If so, Managed Identity may be the simplest way to restrict access. No need to store client secrets/certificates in the API Management + not as flaky as IP whitelisting method.

1. Create an Azure Active Directory Application for the Function App.
2. Enable Authentication/Authorization module on the Function App and reference the AAD app from step 1.
3. Enable a Managed Identity on the APIM instance.
4. Add a `<authentication-managed-identity>` policy to the APIM and reference the AAD app from step 1.

I've blogged about this approach in more detail in [Restrict Azure Functions to API Management with Terraform](https://www.maxivanov.io/restrict-azure-functions-to-api-management-with-terraform/)

Reference:

- [Use managed identities in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity)
- [Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)

Comment: Doesn't this approach only ensure that the request comes from some entity that is authenticated via AAD? Couldn't that be any app or human that has an AAD identity, not just APIM?